# Need to expand /boot partition but not sure if I can

Tags: partitioning, gparted, boot-partition

So I've been having some trouble installing updates lately because my boot partition has run out of space. I did some research to try and find the best way to expand the partition, but after looking at gparted, I'm not sure if it's possible for me to do it without reformatting everything.

Since I can't post pictures here's a little description of what I've got going on on /dev/sda:

**Partition - File System - Mount Point - Size - Used - Flags**

> /dev/sda1------ext4--------------/boot---------94MB - 94MB - boot
>
> /dev/sda2---extended---------------------- 465.67GB
>
> > /dev/sda5-----ext4------------/home----465.67GB - 66GB -
>
> unallocated-1.02MB

Just as an aside, my / partition is installed on the ssd portion of the hybrid drive.

Any comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not clean up /boot instead of growing it? Simply remove older kernel packages you don't need anymore.

Comment: If my boot partition looked like the following, what could I clean up?

abi-3.5.0-17-generic         lost+found
abi-3.5.0-18-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.5.0-19-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.5.0-21-generic         System.map-3.5.0-17-generic
config-3.5.0-17-generic      System.map-3.5.0-18-generic
config-3.5.0-18-generic      System.map-3.5.0-19-generic
config-3.5.0-19-generic      System.map-3.5.0-21-generic
config-3.5.0-21-generic      vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic....

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-3.5.0-{17,18,19}-generic`

Comment: And after you've done another upgrade (3.5.0-26 is the latest), you can also remove 3.5.0-21 :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, when running that, it gives me the following:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-17-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.5.0-17-generic but it is not going to be installed... 

Then something about running apt-get -f install, but I can't do that because I don't have enough space. Thanks in advance for the help btw

Comment: Ooh, you're in a pickle already then. Let's try being a bit more agressive: `sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-{,extra-}3.5.0-{17,18,19}-generic`

Comment: 19 has somehow been removed, but adding the extra to the other two didn't seem to do the trick :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8123/discussion-between-dennis-kaarsemaker-and-brandon-lile)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer that you should purge some old packages, but still 94MB is a bit small.

If you want to resize the boot partition you are going to need to resize the other ones and move everything up. It might take a while, but you only need to do it once. I've not needed to do this for a long time, but the [gparted manual](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-advanced-partition-actions) looks first class.